# Simple Assembler: LACL #05858h

Tags: assembly

i haven't fount anything in the search so far, so i figured i just ask:

I am attending a class, where we are learning stuff about assembler, microprocessors and dsp's. The question in concerning the accumulator, so if i use:

`LACL #05858h`

a) What is in the accumulator now? Number 5858 in hex (`0x16E2`)? The Number 5858?
b) What effect does the `#` have? I know it means immediate, but why cant we leave it out?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `h` in `05858h` denotes a hex number: `05858h` is equal to the decimal number  `22616`. Note that the leading `0` is not necessary here, but it would be required if the first digit was greater than `9`, e.g. `0FF00h`.
The `#` is necessary; the instruction

```
LACL 05858h
```

would load the accumulator with the word at address `05858h` in memory.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, so it would load the accumulator with just `05858h`, right?